# Is it possible to have a bottom footer with a horizontal scrollbar and no vertical scroll bar?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have a layout which uses min-width and works great. So I came to add a footer which I want to stick to the bottom. Firefox will display everything perfectly while with IE, when min-width takes in effect and the vertical scroll bar kicks in, the horizontal scroll bar also appears even thought my content isn't even close to needing it.

I have tried every solution I could find about the bottom footer and they all seem to behave that way.

Is there a solution to this problem or will I have to realize once again that IE is not-so-good? ;)

Thank you.

Comment: You don't have to put "[IE CSS]" in your title.  That's what the tags are for.

Comment: Putting a sample of code that reproduce the problem might help getting some answers ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using overflow:hidden;?

*Edit*:  You might also want to try overflow:auto; with your margins set to margin:0;

Answer (score 1):

You might try overflow-y: hidden;

NOTE: Does NOT validate.

Comment: overflow-x and overflow-y are valid in CSS3.

Comment: ok.. I should have said does not validate in CSS 2.1. Thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 0):

I know that jquery ui has a slider plugin that can duplicate the functionality. Here's a demo that does something similar. 
http://ui.jquery.com/repository/real-world/product-slider/
Might be a bit heavy for your application, but it's worth a look.